# C++ VBO rendering issue

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

This code works like it's supposed to work, renders correctly (didn't post every piece of related code since I think something's wrong with these parts):

```
std::vector<GLuint> vboId;
std::vector< std::vector<GLfloat> > verts;
```

...init:

```
verts[num].push_back(x);
verts[num].push_back(y);
//verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(0);
verts[num].push_back(offset);

verts[num].push_back(x + TILE_SIZE);
verts[num].push_back(y);
//verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(1);
verts[num].push_back(offset);

verts[num].push_back(x + TILE_SIZE);
verts[num].push_back(y + TILE_SIZE);
//verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(1);
verts[num].push_back(offset + zsize);

verts[num].push_back(x);
verts[num].push_back(y + TILE_SIZE);
//verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(0);
verts[num].push_back(offset + zsize);
...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId[num]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts[num].size() * sizeof(GLfloat), verts[num].data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

...render:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboId[num]);

glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(verts[num]),(void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*2));
glVertexPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(verts[num]),0);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, verts[num].size());

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

But when I try to add Z value by modifying the code, everything renders messed up:

...init

```
verts[num].push_back(x);
verts[num].push_back(y);
verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(0);
verts[num].push_back(offset);

verts[num].push_back(x + TILE_SIZE);
verts[num].push_back(y);
verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(1);
verts[num].push_back(offset);

verts[num].push_back(x + TILE_SIZE);
verts[num].push_back(y + TILE_SIZE);
verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(1);
verts[num].push_back(offset + zsize);

verts[num].push_back(x);
verts[num].push_back(y + TILE_SIZE);
verts[num].push_back(0);
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(0);
verts[num].push_back(offset + zsize);
...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId[num]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts[num].size() * sizeof(GLfloat), verts[num].data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

...render:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboId[num]);

glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(verts[num]),(void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*3));
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(verts[num]),0);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, verts[num].size());

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? Why do the first codes work but the last ones don't?

Comment: written by beps, edit by kebs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I solved it.. this code renders it like it's supposed to:

```
glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(GLfloat) * 5,(void*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 3));
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(GLfloat) * 5,(void*)0);
...
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, verts[num].size() / 5);
```

But I'm unsure if it's really correct, I don't see any artifacts but don't really know what's happening behind the scenes..
Thanks for help, if anyone can confirm the code is correct please do

But what I understand here is that glTexCoordPointer(* 5, * 3) starts from third array index (the first texture coordinate) and increases by 5 (index * 5) elements forward each time. And glVertexPointer(* 5, 0) starts from array index 0 and increases also 5 each time.
Therefore:

```
verts[num].push_back(x); // index 0
verts[num].push_back(y); // index 1
verts[num].push_back(0); // index 2
// texture offset
verts[num].push_back(0); // index 3
verts[num].push_back(offset); // index 4
```

I can get back to add more stuff heh https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNvyP.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe your original one is only rendering correctly because the verticies happen to land on relevant co-ordinates. I think the issue is with your stride and initial locations.

Since your array looks like

x-y-z-u-v

The verticies will have stride as well, as they have to jump two floats to reach the next co-ordinate. The texture co-ordinates will also have an initial pointer location.

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, 0);
```

This is to say, for the textures, start at index 3 (u), read two elements (u and v), then move ahead three elements, which will be the next u, as it skips x, y and z.

For the verticies, start at 0 (x), read three elements, x, y and z, then skip two to start at the next x.

Comment: I tried but it still renders incorrectly: [link](http://i.imgur.com/4M40aDx.png) maybe there's something wrong elsewhere

Comment: @beps It could be that it's rendering garbage data outside of the buffer. Your glDrawArrays call should be rendering the number of verticies, not the number of floats. (try changing it to verts[num].size() / 5) Can you provide a link of what it's meant to look like?

Comment: size() / 5 now looks like this [link](http://i.imgur.com/MBBqnXs.png) , it's supposed to look like this, xy 0,0 is in the top left corner [link](http://i.imgur.com/GMnEtmn.png) that's rendered with the original code

Comment: I'm trying to add Z value so I can use depth with other rendered stuff to put them behind or front of the VBO's rendered data. this is my glOrtho but I don't think that affects rendering glOrtho(0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0f, -1.0f, 16777215.0f);

Comment: Do note that the white texture is part of the texture file, I changed it to green in the texture file and that above image link with messed rendering had green instead of white and it's the first tile texture in the file at offset 0,0

Comment: Sorry for comment spam but your suggested codes renders this, I changed perspective and zoomed out. It's like a massive 3D triangle http://i.imgur.com/IL5Cq4f.png and when I look at it, FPS drops from 7200 to around 1000